# sending file to aws with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I'm trying to send a file to aws server. I'm using a angular dropzone. I want to know how it is possible to send the file. I have my aws credentials but not sure how to make the request.

when I drop the file into dropzone I just keep getting 
'POST https://url.com/ 400 (Bad Request)'

```
  angular.extend($scope, {
      dropzoneConfig: {
        'options': {
          'url':'https://url.com',
        },

        'eventHandlers': {
          'sending': function(file, formData, xhr) {
              console.log('sending');
          },
          'success': function(file, response) {
            console.log('sent');
          },
          'error': function() {
            console.log('error');
            $scope.hideDropzone = true;
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficulty.
In short:

1. Read file with fileReader object.
2. Get presigned url from amazon server. (With PHP or other server side script)
3. Send PUT request to the presigned url with encoded file buffer content.
4. If put request is success, show some message to the user.

We workd for one month on our implementation.